# Detecting if stdout is a console with MS Visual compilation, with console provided by mingw64

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, console, mintty

I maintain a command line utility that generates binary data. Data can be redirected towards `stdout` when requested.
This is valid when `stdout` is redirected to a pipe or a file,
but less so when `stdout` is a console, as it would garbage the console.

In order to protect users against such mistake, the program must detect if `stdout` is a console or not, and bail out when it is.

Now, this is nothing new, and a quick look over Internet will find multiple solutions. The main drawback is that there is no "universal" method, and `Visual Studio` requires its own flavor.

The console detector I'm using for Visual has a flaw : it doesn't detect that `stdout` is a console *when* the console is provided by `mingw`, which I believe means that it is `mintty`.

Here is the relevant code section :

```
#if defined(WIN32) || defined(_WIN32)
#  include <io.h>      /* _isatty */
#  include <windows.h> /* DeviceIoControl, HANDLE, FSCTL_SET_SPARSE */
#  include <stdio.h>   /* FILE */
static __inline int IS_CONSOLE(FILE* stdStream) {
    DWORD dummy;
    return _isatty(_fileno(stdStream)) && 
           GetConsoleMode((HANDLE)_get_osfhandle(_fileno(stdStream)), &dummy);
}
#endif
```

Note that the console detector works fine with the built-in Windows console (conhost.exe). It also works fine when the binary is compiled by `mingw64`. So the issue is mostly "compiled with `Visual` + console is `mintty`".

I've been looking around for some potential backup solutions, and found multiple variants of console detector for Visual, using different logics. But none of them would identify `mintty` as a console, they all fail.

I'm wondering if it is a problem with `mintty`, though I would anticipate that if it is, more applications would be impacted. Yet, searching for such issue over Internet yields relatively little complaints, and no solution.

- Is it a known issue ?
- Is there a known solution ?

Comment: `_isatty` looks for character files, which includes the console, COM ports, and also NUL. Detecting the console requires additional calls such as `GetConsoleMode`, so the `_isatty` call in your code is redundant. That said, `GetConsoleMode` will fail if the handle doesn't have read access (e.g. "con" can only be opened for read or write access, but not both, while "conin$" and "conout$" can be opened with read-write access), so this isn't completely reliable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mintty` is a terminal emulator and does not present a console to a running application.  When I need to run a true console program I've got to use `winpty`.  For example `winpty powershell` will allow powershell to run correctly within `mintty`.

It is a known issue that several applications like `git` works around.  This is what I also found.

https://github.com/fusesource/jansi-native/issues/11.

https://github.com/fusesource/jansi-native/commit/461068c67a38647d2890e96250636fc0117074f5

So apparently you should also check if you are connected to a pipe with the following name:

```
/*
 * Check if this could be a MSYS2 pty pipe ('msys-XXXX-ptyN-XX')
 * or a cygwin pty pipe ('cygwin-XXXX-ptyN-XX')
 */
```